# PHP: Data inside database is not showing

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help because my getRecipe.php is not showing the parameters or data shown like my other PHP files: **getCourseType**. It just appears blank and doesn't show anything in my browser.With the **getRecipe.php** it just display blank or nothing but I'm expecting the output like the image below for my getRecipe.php Perhaps you can modify my codes, answer it below and let me check it out if it works. Can you help me display those data of **getRecipe.php** from the database? thanks !

## Screenshot of getCourseType(Which is working)

[image]

## getRecipe.php

```
  <?php
  require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
  $db = new Db_Connect();
  $conn = $db->connect();
  if(isset($_GET['recipeId'])){
     $id = $_GET['recipeId'];
     $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM recipe where id=$id");
  }else{    
      $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM recipe");
  }

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $list = array();
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          array_push($list, $row);
      }
      echo json_encode(array('result' => $list));
  } else {
      echo json_encode("no result");
  }
  ?>
```

## Screenshot of PHPMYADMIN Recipe

Yeah, it has data so it should display whenever I call it....

[image]

Comment: You might have an error on the page and turned off error reporting. Turn it on for level E_ALL, on the very beginning of the script, and see if it tells something - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

try exemple like that :

```
 $id_user=$_POST['id_user'];
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', 'root', '');
 $req = $bdd->prepare('select  *  from event where id_user = ?');
 $req->execute(array($id_user));
//$_SESSION['id']

   $response["events"] = array();

  while(  $donnees = $req->fetch()){
    $endroits = array();
    $endroits ['titre']=$donnees['titre'];
    $endroits ['date']=$donnees['date'];


    array_push($response["events"], $endroits);
   }

 print  json_encode($response);
```